# Do EC2 instances in AWS get deleted after they are terminated?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am new to this. I made an instance and I installed some things on it (git, heroku), and after my assignment was done I terminated it. One day later I log in, and that instance is gone. Do I have to create another one and install same things on it again and again after each time I terminate it?

PPS. Before checking on my previous instance, i created another one, and only that shows up, not my old instance. I am using the free tier.

Comment: Upvoted because I don't know why this was down voted...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, instances are permanently deleted after termination.

If you want to keep the server around, assuming you're using EBS root instances, you can **stop** it, which will not delete the server. Then you can **start** it again when needed.

Comment: will I be billed for just stopping an instance?

Comment: You will not be billed for running an instance, but you *will* be billed for the EBS storage.

Comment: is vagrant better than aws?

Comment: is vagrant + virtualbox better than aws?

Comment: @MuhiburRahim Define "better". They're good for different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ami of the instance. So later you can create an instance using this ami from the point where it been taken for ami